# Abort trap when storing users input into two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, abort

I am going to take in a users input consisting of their identification and their mark, separated by a space. The code compiles and I can enter answers at the prompt, however, at the end of the prompts (end of the first loop) I get an "Abort trap: 6" appearing.

I would appreciate it if you could help me find out why this comment is arising. I read that it could be from me overwriting over other memory, but it looks like my loops do not go beyond what I would want them to loop over (user gives me 10 answers).

I also added ampersands in front of the arrays in scanf, which I found odd to do, but the code did not compile otherwise.

## include

int main (void){

```
char id[10];

int mark[10];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){


    printf("Enter ID and mark: \n");



    scanf(" %s %d", &id[i], &mark[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){

    printf("%c ",id[i]);

}
```

}

Comment: PS. I also used 'gets' after the printf in the first loop, using one array to contain both the id and mark, however, this also resulted in the same "Abort error: 6".

Comment: Are the string you scan using 1 char only ? whuy not use `%c` in the scanf ?

Comment: Sorry for not addressing this.

Comment: The ID I receive will be like: j134432 (one letter, followed by 6 numbers)

Comment: but you are storing it into one char ?

Comment: I would like to take this id and put it into the corresponding index in the id array

Answer (score 0):

I think your ID reading is wrong, your IDs are string of 7 character length while your [`char id[10]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+ids%5B10%5D) is a string of 10 char ( where you intended to use a list of string ), you should use [`char *ids[10]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*ids%5B10%5D) instead.

```
char *ids[10] = { NULL }; // list of 10 string, initialized to NULL
int mark[10];
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    ...
    char* id=malloc(8*sizeof(char)); // allocate a new string to store
    scanf( "%7s %d\n", id, &mark[i] ); // check the result of the scanf to ensure you got the correct input
    ids[i] = id; // store the string at position in the list
}
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
     printf("%s\n", ids[i]);
}
```

Also using a debugger like [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb-man.html) would help you pinpoint where is the error happening in your code. And probably help you figure out your mistake.